# Optimizing MySQL database query

Tags: mysql

I have a huge table, but I know in most cases, only a small portion of the data are used for a query. Is there a way to make MySQL only lookup this small portion? Does "view" help in this case?

Comment: No a view would likely not help performance. Try using where clauses and proper indexing. And anything less than terrabyte sized tables are not huge!

Comment: There are 170 million records, but only 2 million records are often used. It takes about 10 seconds for a query that aggregate these 2 million records. Is there a way to optimize that?

Comment: WEll I can't say without seeing the query and the table structures and the indexes and the explain plan.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply read this article - http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/optimization.html

Optimize indexes, statements/clauses, caching and server itself.

Answer (score 0):

**Many columns**

If you have many columns, be sure to only name the used columns in the `SELECT` statement. This allows MySQL to skip over the unused columns, not returning values that you won't be using anyway.

So, instead of the following query:

```
SELECT *
FROM users
```

Use this type of query:

```
SELECT id, last_name, first_name
FROM users
```

**Many rows**

If you have many rows, add indexes to the columns that you are filtering on using the `WHERE` clause. For example:

```
SELECT id, last_name, first_name
FROM users
WHERE last_name = 'Smith'
```

The above query selects specific columns for all user records where the last name is 'Smith'.

If you have an index on the last_name column, MySQL would be able to locate the records that match the criteria in your WHERE clause very quickly.